# Cannot convert value of type 'String?.Type' to expected argument type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, string, initialization

I'm getting the error stated in the title where var updater is declared.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ProductViewController,
            let index = tableViewProducts.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {

            // Check whether postData array count is greater than index
            let updaterId = postData.count > index ? postData[index] : ""

            // Initialize "productsList" instance and assign the id value and sent this object to next view controller
            var updater = productsList(id: String?, p_name: String?, image: String?, audio: String?)
            updater.id = updaterId
            destination.updater = updater
```

here is my productsList VC:

import Foundation

```
class productsList {

    let id: String?
    let p_name: String?
    let image: String?
    let audio: String?

    init(id: String?, p_name: String?, image: String?, audio: String?) {
        self.id = id
        self.p_name = p_name
        self.image = image
        self.audio = audio
    }

}
```

Comment: Exactly at what line you are getting Issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This

```
var updater = productsList(id: updaterId, p_name: nil, image: nil, audio: nil)
```

Instead of

```
var updater = productsList(id: String?, p_name: String?, image: String?, audio: String?)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass string values (or `nil`) as the parameters not the type `String?`, that's what the error says.

Replace

```
var updater = productsList(id: String?, p_name: String?, image: String?, audio: String?)
updater.id = updaterId
```

with

```
let updater = productsList(id: updaterId, p_name: nil, image: nil, audio: nil)
```

and please conform to the naming convention that class names start with a capital letter.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been staring at this issue for an hour or so, and only your answer helped me to realize what exactly I was doing!

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the issue

```
var updater = productsList(id: String?, p_name: String?, image: String?, audio: String?)
```

When you init your Object ie "ProductList" you must pass an actual value of your fileds "id", "p_name", "image" and "audio".

As now you are sending **"String?"**, this is type of argument where your function is expecting a value for it.

So change it like

```
var updater = productsList(id: ID_OF_PRODUCT, p_name: NAMEOFPRODUCT, image: URLTOIMAGE/IMAGE, audio: AUDIOURL)
```